Email hint android depreacted in Android 14 / API 34
I'm not even able to find official doc for requestEmailHint functiojnnality and below code is depreacted after updating below dependency:
   private fun requestEmailHint() {
    LogUtils.d("requestEmailHint called")
    val accountHintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
            .setHintPickerConfig(CredentialPickerConfig.Builder()
                    .setShowCancelButton(true)
                    .build())
            .setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported(true)
            .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
            .build()

    val options = CredentialsOptions.Builder()
            .forceEnableSaveDialog()
            .build()

    (activity as? BaseActivityV2)?.let {
    val pendingIntent = Credentials.getClient(it, options).getHintPickerIntent(accountHintRequest)
        try {
            emailHintRequestIntentSender.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendingIntent.intentSender).build())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

Debepdency:
def gmsAuthPhoneVersion = '18.0.2'
def gmsAuthVersion = '21.1.0'



implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$gmsAuthVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:$gmsAuthPhoneVersion"


What exactly is deprecated?

HintRequest, CredentialPickerConfig classes

@IshikaSingh did you get any solution?
